# I wnt to know HOW to create TM, TE, and TEM waves; and is it being used in industry?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits

[Transverse Magnetic (TM) and Transverse Electric (TE) modes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78419/transverse-magnetic-tm-and-transverse-electric-te-modes)

So I'm wholly ignorant of any knowledge surrounding these modes, so bear with me here..

One component is infinitesimally small in the first two TE & TM, Could this be done with the biggest ratio transformer (step up for TE and step down for TM) is this an alright assumption?

I assume this could be done in photonics/phononics as well since they are also particle waves, but again, the mechanism escapes the boundaries of my understanding.

What i really want to know, is how to remove either magnetic or electric field in a signal, and why anyone would Want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking about mode transformers; these are extensively used in antennas as they connect to waveguide feeds. The waveguides usually employ TE10 (rectangular) or TE11 (circular) modes, but if you want to feed a horn, say, then you have to shape the field properly to avoid reflection, reduce sidelobes, and reduce cross-polarization coupling, etc. A good horn emits a rather complex combination of hybrid modes. See, e.g., the Potter horn.  Here are a few pictures https://www.google.com/search?q=waveguide+mode+transformers&rlz=1C1LDJZ_enUS502US584&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=619&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=9CeHVJf4KZCcygTX4YLYCw&ved=0CFIQ7Ak